# Using Mechanize (Python) to fill form

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

I want to fill the form on this page using python mechanize and then record the response. How should I do it? When I search for forms on this page using the following code, it shows the form only for the search. How should I locate the form name of the other form with fields such as name, gender etc?

http://aapmaharashtra.org/join-us

Code:

```
import mechanize
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://aapmaharashtra.org/join-us")
for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form
```

Comment: @alecxe Thanks, it helped! I have one more answer. In the form when I select any state, the options in the district field change dynamically. How should I see the new possible options for district using Mechanize?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The form you need (with an `id="form1"`) is loaded dynamically on the fly - this is why you don't see it in the `select_forms()` results.

By using  browser developer tools you may find out that the form is loaded from `http://internal.aamaadmiparty.org/Directory/Format.aspx?master=blank` link.

Here's what you should start with then:

```
import mechanize


br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://internal.aamaadmiparty.org/Directory/Format.aspx?master=blank")
br.select_form(nr=0)

br.form['ctl00$MainContent$txtname'] = 'Test Name'
# fill out other fields

req = br.submit()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: On a side note - it's sometimes easier to look at the code using developer tools to find the end point the form gets posted to, then just use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to post the required info.