# How to submit form in Python?

Tags: python

I was trying to submit details through python on a form on the following [website](http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp).

I tried requests but there is a search box on the site as well(another form).

How do I handle this?
Sample data - TIN - 27680809621V

Answer (score 1):

Try selenium or BeautifulSoup libraries

Comment: How about providing an example in your answer. Right now your 'answer' is more of a comment than an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Mechanize](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize), a library that supports interacting with forms, links and others when crawling or scraping data.

Something like this would be enough:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp')
br.select_form('f1')
br.form['tin'] = '27680809621V'
br.submit()
```

Here are some examples from StackOverflow on how to use Mechanize to fill forms:

- [Using Mechanize (Python) to fill form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294489/using-mechanize-python-to-fill-form)
- [Submitting Forms with Mechanize (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570920/submitting-forms-with-mechanize-python)

Comment: If you are just going to recommend a library and link other answers on this site, why not comment and flag for duplication. Also this feels more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I tried mechanize. I had problems with it. 

import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp'
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name='f1')

It gave me the following error - TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'